# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in C:\Users\gajja\OneDrive\Desktop\user_login\views\update.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

Whenever I click on the update button it shows such kind of error instead of showing me the form  fill field. So help me out with that.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>Form Data</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Form Data</h1>
   <table border="2">
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Message</th>
       <th>Actions</th>
     </tr>
 formData.forEach(function(data, index) { %>
       <tr>
         <td><%= data.name %></td>
         <td><%= data.email %></td>
         <td><%= data.message %></td>
         <td>
           <a href="/update/<%= index %>">Update</a>
           <a href="/delete/<%= index %>">Delete</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
     <% }); %>
   </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Missing open tag ejs is:<%**

Also change update and delete href like:

```html
<a href=`/update/${<%= index %>}`>Update</a>
<a href=`/delete/${<%= index %>}`>Delete</a>
```

```html
 <% formData.forEach(function(data, index) { %>
       <tr>
         <td><%= data.name %></td>
         <td><%= data.email %></td>
         <td><%= data.message %></td>
         <td>
           <a href=`/update/${<%= index %>}`>Update</a>
           <a href=`/delete/${<%= index %>}`>Delete</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
     <% }); %>
```